# Evaluate the natural log e in Scheme

Tags: scheme

e=1/0!+1/1!+1/2!+1/3！……

I wrote the code like that, but whatever I input, it just returns 2....
 Could you help me with that?

```
 (define (fact n)
        (if (= n 0)
            1
            (* n (- n 1))))

    (define (e limit)
            (if (= limit 0)
                1
                (+ (/ 1 (fact limit))  (e (- limit 1)))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a mistake in the `fact` procedure:

```
(define (fact n)
  (if (= n 0)
      1
      (* n (fact (- n 1))))) ; you forgot to recursively call `fact`
```

Test each procedure throughly, a simple unit test would have revealed that the problem was in `fact` and not in the `e` procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Please tell me that this isn't for your homework, that you are just tinkering with Scheme. :)

I do not get `2` for any input to `e`.  I get a divide-by-zero error for any input to `e` besides `0`.

Setting that aside, you have a glaring problem in `fact`.  Maybe the parentheses tripped you up and you have been staring at this too long:

```
(define (fact n)
    (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (- n 1))))
```

...should be:

```
(define (fact n)
    (if (= n 0)
        1
        (* n (fact (- n 1)))))
```

Remember, you can't implement a recursive function...without the function calling itself.

This should solve your problem.

Maybe TAs aren't available to help so quickly these days, but if this is for your homework, you need to work on breaking down the problems you encounter to the simplest elements to survive more programming, which will only get tougher.  Specifically in this case, you needed to stop and ask whether `fact`, on which `e` depends, actually worked, find that it did not, and go from there.